# Understanding set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I came across a question that I need help understanding. So there are two questions and each of them requires me to give 5 positive numbers from the set
$\{x \mid x = 3 \times y\,\textrm{or}\, x = 5 \times y;\; y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$
and $\{x \mid x = 3 \times y\,\textrm{and}\, x = 5 \times z;\, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers. However, what is the difference between the words "or" and "and"?

Comment: As shown by the truth tables: [or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction_(OR)), [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction_(AND)).

Comment: "or" means that you only need one of the conditions to hold (though it is fine if both hold).  "and" means that you need both to hold.  Thus $6$ is in the first set but not the second, while $30$ is in both.  the second set is contained in the first.